# Creating File to sharepoint based on content type

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, power-automate

I am trying to create some files based on content types set in a library that triggers when item is added to a list.

I am using as an action based on a tutorial that i found the "create item" and i place "Documents" on the list selection so the flow gives me the content type Id and all other columns that are needed.

All looks fine but i get an error of:

> To add an item to a document library, use
>   SPFileCollection.Add()\r\nclientRequestId:
>   b008247b-f143-44a7-b914-316fcd9eb7d0\r\nserviceRequestId:
>   df3cbf9e-00cc-8000-97f0-36e3a5627bdb

Is there anything that i can do to edit the flow?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your own template file to your content types. After that you set up your flow as follows:

- Item in list created (trigger action)
- Get your file content using "get file content" action (you can of course use several 
  content types with different template files)
- Create a new file using the "Create file" action giving it the file Content of your 
  previous action